# launching ZTE MF92 HSDPA modem

Tags: modem

I get this error when I try to launch my zte modem using the `sudo wvdial` command on terminal

```
julioceaser@julioceaser-NP300E5V:~$ sudo wvdial
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot set information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Configuration does not specify a valid phone number.
--> Configuration does not specify a valid login name.
--> Configuration does not specify a valid password.
julioceaser@julioceaser-NP300E5V:~$ sudo gedit /etc/wvdial.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

just do this...

```
sudo gedit /etc/wvdial.conf
```

when it opens up....look for what is written next to "Dialer"!!! Just like this  →[Dialer mts]

if you have found that out then...do this...

```
sudo wvdial [the name you found next to "Dialer" in the above mentioned method]
```

for example... `sudo wvdial mts` (here "mts" is the name i found written next to "Dialer" in the above mentioned method in my case)

thats it!!! Hope it works !!!